# free falling object with air resistance?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, newtonian-gravity, drag, free-fall

we already know that if we plot speed vs time of free falling object it will be 
y=gx graph because we know the acceleration is gravity.

If it have air-resistance acceleration will be change right?.

So how we can plot the speed vs time graph of free falling object with air resistance ?

It have some equations or not.

because i want to plot it by using python.

Thanks.

sorry about my english.

[image: example graph from google]

This picture i saw from google but i want to make it by coding

Comment: Have you tried searching how one models air resistance or air drag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may (or may not) know drag is dependant on the square of velocity.

Have a read for a bit more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_%28physics%29

You can see it is also dependant on various properties of the object and the fluid it is travelling through. Changing the *"coeff"* parameter in the code below will change how the drag is modelled. As requested:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

coeff=0.2

times = np.linspace(0,3.5,100)
tstep = (max(times)-min(times))/len(times)

no_drag_velocities = 9.8*times

a=0
v=0
drag_velocities = []
for i in times:
    drag_velocities.append(v)
    a=9.8-coeff*v**2*tstep
    v=v+a*tstep

plt.plot(times,no_drag_velocities,label="Without Drag") 
plt.plot(times,drag_velocities,label="With Drag")
plt.xlabel("Time [s]")
plt.ylabel("Speed [m/s]")
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image: Drag Plot]